# Make Discord Bot react to own embed? (Discord.js v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding my own discord bot for a couple of friends and myself, and I can't figure out how to make the bot react to its own embedded message.
I can figure out how to do it in the previous versions of Discord.js, but with Discord.js v14, I unfortunately can't...

This is the code I want it to react to:

```
if (command === 'embedMessage') {
    message.delete(); // Deletes previous message
    message.channel.send({ // This is the embed
      embeds: [ new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription('Description')
        .setColor("Green")
      ],
    });
  }
```

I have already tried using the `message.react('');`, but this only works for messages sent by users.

I've also read https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages, but nowhere is it stated how to do it with embedded messages...
I also can't seem to find anything on discord.js v14 here on stackoverflow, because it's so new.

Comment: _"I can figure out how to do it in the previous versions of Discord.js, but with Discord.js v14, I unfortunately can't"_. There is no change in this; `send` returns a promise and once it's resolved, the message that your bot sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason that `message.react('');` is only working for message sent by the user is that `message` is representing the message of the user sent, while the message that the bot sent is a different one.

To have the bot's message reacted after it was sent, you can use the `.then()` method.

```js
message.channel.send({ // This is the embed
    embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription('Description')
        .setColor("Green")
    ],
}).then((msg) => {
    msg.react(''); // Emoji React
})
```

`msg` defined within the method is representing the message that the bot has sent, which allows the bot to add reaction on it.